# Is there simplified expression for if(variable1){variable2="string:"+variable1} in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntactic-sugar

I've recently learned in javascript `variable=variable||"aaaa"` means

```
if(variable){return variable;}
else{var variable = "aaaa";}
```

Then, is there any syntactic sugar which is substituted for the following code?

```
if(variable1){var variable2 = "aaaa" + variable1);}
else{variable2 = "";)
```

I tried `var variable2=("aaaa"+variable1)||"";` but it doesn't work probably because the left term of `||` can't be false due to `"aaaa"`.

Comment: `variable=variable||"aaaa" means` no, it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator for this. If the test (the first expression) is truthy, then the expression resolves to what comes after the `?`, else the expression resolves to what comes after the `:`:

```
var variable2 = variable1
  ? "aaaa" + variable1
  : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't do this, but maybe you like it:

```js
var variable2 = (variable1 || '') && "aaaa" + variable1;
```

Unfortunately in this case I didn't find a way of not repeating "variable1" in the statement.